# Ruby process problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process

I have this code:

```
pid1 = fork {
  system("rails new #{name_without_syms}")
}

Process.waitpid(pid1)
cd("#{name_without_syms}")

pid2 = fork {
  system("rails g controller Main index")
}

Process.waitpid(pid2)
rm_default_files("#{sh.pwd}")
cp_files("#{sh.pwd}")
```

If I run it once, it will work, but the next time it will infinitely run, but if I will KILL all Ruby processes, it will work. After run once, I have two Ruby processes (ruby, ruby *zombie*).

How can I make run it next time and kill all Ruby processes in the end?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to make run it next time? How to kill all ruby processes in the end?

Comment: Yep, I can use this: system("killall -9 ruby"), but I think it's not correct

Comment: If you are fine with halting your main process to wait on the child processes, why do you want to use `fork` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

At teardown or at the end of the code you require your fork process to be running run the commands below.

The wait will prevent zombie processes...

```
Process.kill "TERM", pid
Process.wait pid
```